# Can not get image information from Silverlight RichTextEditor

Tags: silverlight, image, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to use the Silverlight RichTextEditor in our website. Now we'd like to translate the content in richtextbox into HTML code to save and load.

However, as we know, the richtextbox control does not support the UIelements output. When we insert an image in the richtextbox, the richtextbox would use a inlineUIcontainer to show this image. The property Richtextbox.xaml does not include any information about the image. It just shows the code like "".

Does anyone have this problem and handle it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichTextBox.Xaml strips out a lot of things, as a security safeguard (more for the setter than the getter as far as I recall, but it does it both ways so there are no round-trip surpises).

I recommend looking at the XAML Serializer written by David Poll on his blog (here: http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/07/25/to-xaml-with-love-an-experiment-with-xaml-serialization-in-silverlight/ ) as it can serialize RTB awesomely well (it's in fact one of the test cases he shows).  David was a PM on the Silverlight XAML Parser in SL4, so he knows an awful lot about XAML.

But be careful when setting the .Xaml property, as you could mistakenly end up spinning up InlineUIContainer elements which load resources into your AppDomain that you don't want in there, so make sure you control the inputs or you strip them yourself very carefully.

Comment: Thanks Austin. It seems that we can get the img information from the Blocks of RichTextBox. But I still not know how to do this.

Comment: If you grab David's library, full source is provided, so you could step through how he's doing it if you want to do it yourself for some reason - though really I'd recommend just using his library, it's pretty awesome (and he recently added Windows Phone 7 support, so that work would already be done for you if you ever want to go to the phone).

Comment: Thanks again! David's library is awesome!